# Selecting dictionary nested in a list by index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Here is am example of the list:

```
{'Item': 'milk', 'Price': '2.0', 'Quantity': '2'}, {'Item': 'egg', 'Price': '12.0', 'Quantity': '1'}]
```

Here is my code:

```
def edit_items(info):
xy = info

print('Index |       Orders')
for x in enumerate(xy):
    print('\n')
    print(x)
    
choice = int(input('Which entry would you like to edit? Choose by index. :'))
print(x[choice])
```

Id like the user to able to chose an entry by index, and allow them to edit information inside the dictionary.

So far my code prints out:

```
Index |       Orders


(0, {'Item': 'milk', 'Price': '2.0', 'Quantity': '2'})


(1, {'Item': 'egg', 'Price': '12.0', 'Quantity': '1'})
```

But i have no idea how to choose one, assign It to a variable and carry out the ability to edit whats inside.

Cheers. Nalpak_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def edit_items(info):
    xy = info

    # to make multiple edits.
    while True:
        print('Index |       Orders')
        for x in range(len(xy)):
            print(x,xy[x])
    
        choice = int(input('Which entry would you like to edit?\nChoose by index: '))
        print(xy[choice])
        edit = input('What you want to edit: ')   # Key val of dict 
        value = input("Enter: ")    # Value for the specific key in dict
        xy[choice][edit] = value
        print('list updated.')
        print(xy[choice])

        more_edits = input('\nDo you want to make more edits?(y/n): ')
        if more_edits == 'n':
            break

edit_items(info)
```

this will help you make multiple edits.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed to work off of ! thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit an item in a dictionary, you can easily do it by accessing it by the key.

First, we set up the data

```
xy = [{'Item': 'milk', 'Price': '2.0', 'Quantity': '2'}, {'Item': 'egg', 'Price': '12.0', 'Quantity': '1'}]
```

Then if I understood you correctly, this `edit_items` method should do exactly what you need:

```
def edit_items(i):
    name = input('Type in a new item name: ')
    xy[i]['Item'] = name  # 'Item' is the key.
```

Everything else is pretty much the same:

```
print('Index |       Orders')
for x in enumerate(xy):
    print('\n')
    print(x)

choice = int(input('Which entry would you like to edit? Choose by index. :'))
print(xy[choice])
edit_items(choice)
print(xy)
```

If you want, you can also use `input` for getting a key (property) of an item you want to edit.